# Replace a full line, if that line has matched string (Solaris #!/usr/xpg4/bin/sh)

Tags: shell, sed, sh, solaris, solaris-10

I have a text file which has a particular line something like

```
sometext sometext sometext SEARCHED sometext sometext sometext
```

I need to replace the whole line above with

```
modified due to security issue
```

If `SEARCHED` is found in above line

I need to write a shell script for this. How can I achieve this using `sed` for solaris #!/usr/xpg4/bin/sh shell?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an awk version:

```
nawk '/SEARCHED/ {
    print "modified due to security issue";next}
    1' file > file.patched
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to edit the original files, use `ed`:

```
# I do not know if your shell supports <<<
ed -s textfile <<< $',s/.*SEARCHED.*/modified due to security issue/g\nw'
```

When you can't use above solution, use a few lines:

```
ed -s textfile << EOF
,s/SEARCHED/modified due to security issue/g
w
q
EOF
```